# MySQL query - Date Range

Tags: mysql, grafana

Hi I'm using the MySQL query below along side Grafana, and data relating to my electricity usage. The data collected ranges from late 2021 to current date, however the result only ranges from December 21 to November 22.

```
SELECT
Time AS "time",
SUM(Rate/800) as kWh
FROM Log 
GROUP BY MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(time, "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Can someone kindly assist with amending the query to display all relevant months from 2021 to 2023 and so on please.

Comment: check the solution of your post!

Comment: Please provide the output of `CREATE TABLE Log` and a few rows of data as a markdown table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT
Concat(YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(Time, "%Y-%m-%d")),'-', MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(Time, "%Y-%m-%d"))) as month,
SUM(Rate/800) as kWh
FROM Log 
GROUP BY YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(Time, "%Y-%m-%d")), MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(Time, "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Comment: Sorry but I get the error "db has no time column: no time column found".

Comment: Can you test using Time instead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Please add your table structure and some sample data to your question.

Your current query is [non-deterministic](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html#:%7E:text=values%20chosen%20are-,nondeterministic,-%2C%20which%20is%20probably), and if you had [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) enabled, would be failing with a 1055 error. You can read more about [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).

You are grouping by `MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(time, "%Y-%m-%d"))` which will return 1 for `2021-01-02`, `2022-01-03` and `2023-01-04`. You need to group by both the year and month.

If you run this modified version of your query you should be able to see what is happening:

```
SELECT
    MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`Time`, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS `m`,
    MIN(`Time`) AS `min_time`,
    MAX(`Time`) AS `max_time`,
    SUM(`Rate`/800) AS `kWh`
FROM `Log`
GROUP BY MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`Time`, '%Y-%m-%d'));
```

Your use of `STR_TO_DATE()` appears unnecessary as you are using the standard date format `%Y-%m-%d`.

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(`Time`, '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AS `time`,
    SUM(`Rate`/800) AS `kWh`
FROM `Log`
GROUP BY `time`
```

With the date format `'%Y-%m'`, `2021-01-02`, `2022-01-03` and `2023-01-04` will be returned as `2021-01`, `2022-01` and `2023-01` respectively, and grouped in the correct month.

Comment: Using this I get the error ""db has no time column: no time column found".

Comment: I have modified the query to return a _"mock"_ datetime called `time`. This gives grafana a column called `time` with a datetime value for its time series but still allows for grouping by `%Y-%m`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to get your desired output :

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Time, "%Y-%m-%d"),"%Y-%m") AS "Month", 
  SUM(Rate / 800) as kWh
FROM 
  Log  
GROUP BY 
  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Time, "%Y-%m-%d"),"%Y-%m"), Time 
ORDER BY 
  STR_TO_DATE(Time, "%Y-%m-%d");
```

**Results looks like :**

| **Month** | **kWh** |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01 | 1700773808 |
| 2022-02 | 1770840497 |
| 2022-04 | 1741656455 |
| 2022-05 | 1738120832 |
| 2023-01 | 1752779938 |

Comment: I get the error "db has no time column: no time column found".